# BizTalk Server 2013 R2: Warning in a Receive Location with SFTP

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

A client has a Receive Location in BizTalk Server 2013 R2. When it polls the SFTP server (Microsoft's) we received the following warning:

```
The adapter "SFTP" raised an error message. Details 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Number must be either non-negative and less than 
or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.
Parameter name: millisecondsTimeout
```

Why do we get this warning?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your settings for that port? Blacking out any sensitive information of course.

Comment: We are using PublicKeyAuthentication as the ConnectionMode. And then we points to a ppk-file.

Comment: The error is complaining specification about millisecondsTimeout.  As this property is not available in the adapter settings, it must be in a config file.  Try looking at the BizTalk & machine config files.